# Samba server with domain authentication

Tags: linux, authentication, samba, rdp

I need to configure samba server. My question is - how to configure access to this server by rdp for samba users?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify your question...are you asking how to provide RDP access to a Linux system? That doesn't really have much to do with Samba.

Comment: @user1581508: do you want to enable domain authentication on this server? On file shares or remote access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`xrdp`](http://www.xrdp.org/) supports RDP under linux; it acts as a broker for [`vncserver`](http://www.realvnc.com/) displays and automagically multiplexes the vnc displays to different user without needing to permanently allocate a display to them (as you normally do with VNC).  [`xrdp`](http://www.xrdp.org/) also encrypts your traffic with [RC4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4).

I included my tweaks to make it use blackboxwm instead of the default wm.

By default, `xrdp` uses local authentication.  If you want to authenticate against a Windows domain (it's a little unclear what you're trying to do), you can use [`pam_ldap`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/pam_ldap)

---

```
## /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
[globals]
bitmap_cache=yes
bitmap_compression=yes
port=3389
crypt_level=low
channel_code=1

[xrdp1]
name=sesman-Xvnc
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1

[xrdp2]
name=console
lib=libvnc.so
ip=127.0.0.1
port=5900
username=na
password=ask

[xrdp3]
name=vnc-any
lib=libvnc.so
ip=ask
port=ask5900
username=na
password=ask

[xrdp4]
name=sesman-any
lib=libvnc.so
ip=ask
port=-1
username=ask
password=ask

[xrdp5]
name=rdp-any
lib=librdp.so
ip=ask
port=ask3389

[xrdp6]
name=sesman-X11rdp
lib=libxup.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
```

---

```
## /etc/xrdp/sessman.ini
ListenAddress=127.0.0.1
ListenPort=3350
EnableUserWindowManager=1
UserWindowManager=startwm.sh
DefaultWindowManager=startwm.sh

[Security]
AllowRootLogin=1
MaxLoginRetry=4
TerminalServerUsers=tsusers
TerminalServerAdmins=tsadmins

[Sessions]
MaxSessions=10
KillDisconnected=0
IdleTimeLimit=0
DisconnectedTimeLimit=0

[Logging]
LogFile=/var/log/xrdp-sesman.log
LogLevel=DEBUG
EnableSyslog=0
SyslogLevel=DEBUG

[X11rdp]
param1=-bs
param2=-ac
param3=-nolisten
param4=tcp

[Xvnc]
param1=-bs
param2=-ac
param3=-localhost
param3=-nolisten
param4=tcp
```

---

File: `/etc/xrdp/startwm.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

# change the order in line below to run to run whatever window manager you
# want, default to kde

SESSIONS="blackbox gnome-session fluxbox startxfce4 startkde xterm"

#start the window manager
wm_start()
{
  if [ -f ~/.xsession ]
  then
    . ~/.xsession
  fi

  return 0
}

pre_start()
{
  if [ -f /etc/profile ]
  then
    . /etc/profile
  fi
  if [ -f ~/.bash_profile ]
  then
    . ~/.bash_profile
  else
    if [ -f ~/.bash_login ]
    then
      . ~/.bash_login
    else
      if [ -f ~/.profile ]
      then
        . ~/.profile
      fi
    fi
  fi
  return 0
}


post_start()
{
  if [ -f ~/.bash_logout ]
  then
    . ~/.bash_logout
  fi
  return 0
}

if [ -r /etc/default/locale ]; then
  . /etc/default/locale
  export LANG LANGUAGE
fi

pre_start
wm_start
post_start

exit 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to use RDP on a Linux server? It's a proprietary protocol from Microsoft.

If you want remote access on your server, use SSH.

If you want a GUI to Samba, use SWAT (webapp).

If you want remote graphical access, use X11 forwarding capabilities of ssh. But there is no GUI to Samba eitherway so...

Comment: If he wants a remote desktop like RDP he could use VNC...